# Place text under an image without moving the image(s)?

Tags: html, css

I've got a couple of images lined up next to each other, that part works fine. However, I want to place text under each of the images, but when i try to do so (by using 'br' or by creating its own 'div') the image creates its own row and pushes the other images down. I understand why it does that but I find it difficult to fix the issue. Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-team">
    <div class="team">
        <h2>Our team</h2>
        <div class="team-members">
            <img src="test1.png">
            <img src="test1.png">
            <img src="test1.png">
            <img src="test1.png">
            <img src="test1.png">
            <img src="test1.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.container-team {
    background-color: #eee;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.team {
    margin:0 auto; 
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.team h2 {
    color: #0E8DBD;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.team-members {
    background: #eee;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.team-members img {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Here are also 2 images to make it more clear of what's happening:

[This is what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52vif.png)

[This is what happens when I give an image its own 'div'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y02cf.png)

any help is appreciated, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display property of `div` elements are `block` by default. Try something like this:

```
<div class="team-member">
  <img src="image.png">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>

.team-member {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
}
```

Take a look at this working example. Hope this is the result you want to achieve: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ogocx9s5/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for teaching me this.

Comment: You are welcome. Edited the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="container-team">
<div class="team">
    <h2>Our team</h2>
    <div class="team-members">
        <div>
            <img src="test1.png">
            <img src="test1.png">
            <img src="test1.png">
            <img src="test1.png">
            <img src="test1.png">
            <img src="test1.png">
        </div>
        <p>Your Text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You'll have to format the text more than that to get it to line up with each image, but it should get it onto the next line.

Comment: I've tried playing around with the text, didn' save any of the code because it didn't work unfortunately. But maybe I haven't tried what you got in mind.

Comment: it works in full screen, but it doesn't go together with responsive elements. Thanks anyway.